# Skipping files from coverage

Tags: python, testing, code-coverage

I have a very different requirement to exclude some files from test coverage.

I have a few files which are meant to work on Linux and not on Mac OS X and based on the underline platform I either run the test or don't. I have addressed running test cases based on platform, but need to somehow exclude that particular file from test coverage as well.

Can I apply the condition for the platform to a config file where we omit files from coverage?

Comment: The purpose of the coverage result is not too show 100% but to have 100% coverage. If code is not covered it should be shown.

Answer (score 0):

Most code coverage tools will allow you to configure which files you are measuring code coverage for. The exact answer will depend on the coverage tool you are using.

As you have tagged python, I am going to assume you are using the coverage tool (from `pip install coverage`). In this case, you can use the `omit` option in the settings to remove the files you don't want to measure. More information can be found in their [documentation](https://coverage.readthedocs.io/en/v4.5.x/source.html).